# Exponential map of cotangent bundle and Morse theory on based loop space

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ds.dynamical-systems, morse-theory

Consider $M$ to be a compact manifold and $q_0,q_1\in M$. Let $L_t$ be a lagrangian and $\mathcal{E}_L$ the lagrangian action functional on the based loop space $\Omega(M,q_0,q_1)$ defined as $\mathcal{E}_L(q(t)):=\int _0^{1}L(t,q(t),\dot q(t))dt$. Assume that the lagrangian $L_t$ is nice enough so that we can do classic Morse theory on $\Omega(M,q_0,q_1)$, i.e., we have the Palais-Smale condition , the morse indexes are finite and bounded from below. Now consider $u:[0,\infty]\times [0,1]\rightarrow T^*M$ such that $\pi(u(0,t))\in W^{u}(q)$, where $q$ is a critical point of $\mathcal{E}_L$.

I started thinking about the following problem. Suppose that we have a vector field $Y$ along $u$ such that $d\pi_{u(0,t)}Y(0,t)\in T_{\pi(u(0,t))}W^{u}(q)$. And suppose that we have a metric $g$ in $T^*M$ such that $\pi: T^*M\rightarrow M$ is a riemannian submersion (I am considering a riemannian submersion just because maybe it makes things simpler, ideally we could consider $g$ to be any metric), can we say that $\pi(\exp_{u(0,t)}Y(0,t))\in W^{u}(q)$? Or can we find a specific metric $g$ on $T^*M$ such that the statement is true ? Or perhaps maybe take the exponential with respect to a family of metrics ?

I am been thinking about this for a while but I have made zero progress. All that I can figure out is that $\pi(\exp_{u(0,t)}Y(0,t))$ will have to be in some unstable manifold for some critical point of the lagrangian action functional, but I can't say much about what this critical point is.

Any insight or ideas are appreciated.